# Hot to use assets javascript

Tags: php, symfony

I create own bundle in Symfony2:

**Steve/TestBundle**

and in **Steve/TestBundle/Resources/public/js**

i add own file **main.js** and next use Symfony2 command - *assets:install*.

In: **Steve/TestBundle/Resources/views/home.html.twig** I make:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/bundles/stevetest/js/main.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This working ok, but if I make some changes then i must again use *assets:install*.

Is possible to making changes without still use *assets:install*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-1" because you have to read first the Symfony2 documentation/quickstart/cookbook ! :)

For your question you can use "symlink" with the "asset:install" cmd to create a symbolic link (like the unix cmd "ln -s")

So if you check the doc, you have two possibilities :

- With Symfony2 cmd -> "php app/console asset:install your_path/ --symlink"
- Or in the composer.json file :

Code :

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
}
```